# The width transition not working in tailwindcss

Tags: transition, tailwind-css

I am a newbie for tailwindcss.Today I found the width transition not working in tailwindcss when I want to toggle this

[image]

to

[image]

In the process I want to the width change is smooth.

This is my approach:

```html
  const navigationRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const toggle = () => {
    navigationRef.current?.classList.toggle('w-[300px]');
  }

<div ref={navigationRef} className='relative w-[80px] h-[420px] bg-white rounded-[10px] overflow-hidden shadow-sidebar transition duration-500'>
...
</div>
...
<div
  onClick={toggle}
  className='toggle absolute topCenterY right-[-20px] w-[40px] h-[40px] bg-[#f5f5f5] cursor-pointer border-[5px] border-[#6843d1] rounded-full' >
</div>
```

Notice that I want to toggle *w-[80px]* to *w-[300px]*.

I also attempt to use *scale*:

```html
  const toggle = () => {
    navigationRef.current?.classList.toggle('transform');
  }

<div ref={navigationRef} className='... scale-x-[3.75] duration-500'>
</div>
...
```

[image]

Then, I failed.

So, is there a solution for this?

Comment: I solve it just change *transition* to *transition-all* Inadvertently! What?
One more thing is I change this code 
```
navigationRef.current?.classList.toggle('active')
```
to 
```
navigationRef.current?.classList.toggle('w-[300px]')
```
Because it did not work just now. But it worked before I ask the question. 

Confusing...